# Should it be considered as a prepositional phrase or a determiner?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, quantifiers, partitives

> He drank half of a half gallon of milk.

Should I divide it into ‘of a half gallon’ and ‘of milk,’ or should I divide it into ‘half of’ and ‘a half gallon of’?

Comment: Half of half a gallon is a quart! Why say it in such a cumbersome way? (Oh, I see the expression came from an answer to your previous question.)

Comment: @Kate Bunting Because I’m cumbersome.

Comment: As @stangdon implied, the only reason for saying it that way would be if you were talking about a half-gallon container.

Comment: @Kate Bunting I mean, ‘half of’ modifies ‘a half gallon’ or ‘milk’ or anything?

Comment: Using brackets quasi-mathematically, I suppose (he drank half of) (a half-gallon of milk) would mean that there was another half-gallon of milk he didn't drink, whereas (he drank half of a half-gallon) (of milk) does not. In speech you can distinguish if you are careful, but I don't think you can in written text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, note that there is a difference between "half **a** gallon of..." and "**a** half-gallon of...".

A measurement before a noun is a determiner if it tells you *how much of* something there is. For example:

- 5 litres of water
- A pint of milk
- 3 ounces of flour

Sometimes, when items are packaged in a specific quantity, people start to refer to that item by a compound noun that includes its measurements. I believe that "a half-gallon of milk" refers to milk sold in a container that contains half a gallon.

From a mathematical point of view "*half* of a *half-gallon of milk*" is of course a quarter of a gallon, commonly known as a 'quart'. But, in your example, they appear to be using "a half gallon of milk" as a compound noun for the bottle, and are simply noting that they drank half of it. So, the first 'half' is a determiner relating to the "half gallon of milk".